# ¿Cómo cambiar color de fondo (background) a una jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Sucede que en una misma página cargo varias jqGrids, pero para que se vean más ordenadas necesito darle un tono de fondo diferente a algunas de ellas; ya tengo cargado en la página un tema para las mismas grids, pero necesito crear esa diferencia visual entre una y otra.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función formatter:

Post: 
http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=2678